# Mapping diagonal

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, vectorization

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
idx = ['H',"A","B","C","D"]
idxp = idx[1:] + [idx[0]]
idxm = [idx[-1]] + idx[:-1]
idx, idxp, idxm
j = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
J = pd.DataFrame(j, index=idx, columns=idx)
np.fill_diagonal(J.values, 0)
J
```

[image]

As an output, I would like get the array such that:

- we have zeros everywhere in the lower part of the matrix below and in the diagonal
- have values in the upper part of the matrix calculated by taking the numbers just above the diagonal of the matrix J, therefore the vector v = [1, 7, 13, 19].
- Using v, calculate the first row as the cumulative sum of v from
  start to end and obtain [1, 8, 21, 40]
- Using v, calculate the second row the cumulative sum of v from the second index to the end and obtain [7, 20, 39]
- etc until reach the last index of v

In other words, that would give us the matrix below:

```
m_exp = np.array([[0,1,8,21,40],
             [0,0,7,20,39],
             [0,0,0,13,32],
             [0,0,0,0,19],
             [0,0,0,0,0],
             ])
```

The best way I have found so far to calculate this matrix is by using the code below:

```
travelup = np.array([np.pad(np.cumsum(J.values.diagonal(1)[n:]), (n+1,0), 'constant') for n in range(J.values.shape[0])])
```

However this involved a comprehension list and in practice my matrix is much bigger and this code is called thousands of time.

Is there any way to transform the process by using a mapping to make it faster avoiding looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few methods are listed.

I. Basic method

```
a = J.values
p = np.r_[0,a.ravel()[1::a.shape[1]+1]] # or np.r_[0,np.diag(a,1)]
n = len(p)
out = np.triu(np.broadcast_to(p,(n,n)),1).cumsum(1)
```

`p` and `n` would be re-used in alternatives listed next.

A. Alternative #1

Alternatively with `broadcasted-multiplication` to get the final output -

```
out = (~np.tri(n, dtype=bool)*p).cumsum(1)
```

B. Alternative #2

Alternatively with `outer-subtraction` on cumsum -

```
c = p.cumsum()
out = np.triu(c-c[:,None])
```

C. Alternative #3

Alternatively with `np.tri` to replace `np.triu` -

```
out = (c-c[:,None])*~np.tri(n, dtype=bool)
```

`c` would be re-used in alternatives listed next.

II. With `numexpr`

For large arrays, leverage multi-cores with `numexpr`. Hence, the alternatives would be -

```
import numexpr as ne

out = ne.evaluate('(c-c2D)*M',{'c2D':c[:,None],'M':~np.tri(n, dtype=bool)})
```

A. Alternative #1

```
out = ne.evaluate('(c-c2D)*(~M)',{'c2D':c[:,None],'M':np.tri(n, dtype=bool)})
```

B. Alternative #2

```
r = np.arange(n)
out = ne.evaluate('(c-c2D)*(r2D<r)',{'c2D':c[:,None],'r2D':r[:,None]})
```